# ASP.NET MVC 3: Using Global.asax MapRoutes to migrate a single-client site to a multi-client site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a site that was originally intended for customers of a single client but is now being adapted to serve the customers of multiple clients. Because the site can be used anonymously (Authentication provides enhanced functionality but is not necessary to use the site), I need to be able to set the "Company ID" simply by virtue of a certain URL being accessed.

To accomplish this, I added a MapRoute to my global.asax and am using that to set a Company ID in the session when a specific company's page is landed on (e.g. http://sitename.com/Companies/BurgerHeaven). Once there, my SetCompany action sets the Company ID in session and then passes through to the default Home/Index view. All subsequent pages fall back on the default {controller}/{action}/{id} route and the Company ID stored in the session allows the UI and other customizations to be set accordingly. This works great, except when a user tries to do something after the session has expired, the site no longer knows the company ID and falls back to its default UI and settings.

If I were to change the default route to Companies/{CompanyID}/{controller}/{action}/{id} and change the URLs on all my actions accordingly, would this work? Is there a better approach?

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Companies",
            "Companies/{CompanyID}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "SetCompany" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```